# Forward declaration friend

Tags: c++, friend

I have two classes A and B, where I would like to access the private members of B from A.

```
class A; // Forward declaration    

class B {
    friend class A; // A is a friend of B

    A a; // error: 'B::a' uses undefined class 'A'
private:
    int i;
};

class A {

public:
    B *m_b;

    A(B *i_b) : m_b(i_b) {}; // legal access due to friendship
};
```

However, I do not understand why I get the following error:
'B::a' uses undefined class 'A'

Comment: `A` is an *incomplete type* at that point, so the compiler doesn't know its size.

Comment: A should be forward-declared and defined before B. Then it'll work.

Comment: Revert your classes order and make forward declaration of the class B instead of A.

Comment: You cannot store a concrete instance of `A` without knowing its definition (and therefore its size).  Flip your declarations around and forward declare `B`, since you can store a pointer to `B` without needing the whole class definition.

Comment: You can't declare `A a` after a forward declaration alone: the type must be completely defined to be used like that.

Comment: It's not clear why you need `friend class A;` Nothing in `A` is accessing the `private` parts of `B`.